# Fetch second word in a string until '(' or ' ' encountered

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I want to fetch the second word in a string like in the code below, I'm trying to get the function's name `unstring`. But I need a regex that fetches me the second word until '(' or a space is encountered.

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('FUNCTION unstring(i_string    VARCHAR2', '(\S*)(\S)', 1, 2) 
FROM DUAL;
```

With this regex, I get `unstring(i_string` as the result. I'm trying to fetch the function's name so it's not necessary that a function have arguments, hence the '(' or ' ' encountered condition.

Comment: [`(\S+)\s*\(`](https://regex101.com/r/UbvyeH/1)

Comment: @Tushar It doesn't work.

Comment: same as @Tushar said, except it needs another * : `(\S+)\s*\(*

Comment: Try `(\\S+)\\s*\\(` and check first captured group.

Comment: @Tushar `(\\S+)\\s*\\(` gives an unmatched parentheses error so I tried to escape the last '(' as `SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('FUNCTION unstring(i_string    VARCHAR2', '(\\S+)\\s*\\\(', 1, 2)
FROM DUAL;` This too doesn't work. I'm not too good with regex so it would be great if you could be more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\w+` to match a single word and `\s+` to match whitespace between the two words. Capture the second one:

```
select regexp_substr('FUNCTION unstring(i_string    VARCHAR2','^\w+\s+(\w+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) from dual
```

The pattern means:

- `^` - start of string anchor
- `\w+` - 1 or more letters/digits/`_`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Capturing group 1 matching 1+ word chars (letters/digits/`_`)

The last `1` argument tells `regexp_substr` to return the contents of the first capturing group.